# I was trying to use fisher.test for two variables using tbl_summary, since one cell in each variable is small. FEXACT error 40. Out of workspace

Tags: r

I received the following error:

```
There was an error in 'add_p()/add_difference()' for variable 'gleason', p-value omitted:
Error in stats::fisher.test(structure(c(6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, : FEXACT error 40.
Out of workspace.
There was an error in 'add_p()/add_difference()' for variable 'SEER_registry', p-value omitted:
Error in stats::fisher.test(structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, : FEXACT error 40.
Out of workspace.
```

No P-values printed for "gleason" and "SEER_registry", since as you can see in the figures, there are cells with extreme small value.

I carefully went through the related questions and answers, but none of them worked for me.

Below is my current code:

```
table1 <- prostate_v4 %>% tbl_summary(include = c(age_newcat, race, marital_newcat, year_of_diagnosis, PSA, 
                                  gleason, T_stage, survival_months, cat_pos_core, 
                                  surg_newcat, radiation_newcat, chemotherapy, phys, urology_total, 
                                  urology_TPC, rad_oncology, hospital_beds, med_income, less_HS, 
                                  with_HS_more, college, poverty_1, poverty_2, poverty_3,
                                  poverty_4, poverty_5, poverty_6, poverty_7, deep_poverty,
                                  SEER_registry),
                                  by = watchful_waiting) %>% add_p(test = list(c("gleason", "SEER_registry") ~ "fisher.test"))
      

                                                        
table1 %>% as_flex_table() %>% flextable::save_as_docx(table1, path = '/Users/.../table1.docx')
```

[image]!
[image]

Comment: Fisher's exact test is a permutation test.  It compares your table to all possible tables with the same marginal counts.  There are just too many of those, so you need to use an approximate test, e.g. by setting `hybrid = TRUE` or `simulate.p.value = TRUE` in the `fisher.test()` arguments.

Comment: I tried add_p(test = list(c("gleason", "SEER_registry") ~ "fisher.test(simulate.p.value = TRUE)")), but not work

Comment: Without seeing reproducible code (including the dataset!), I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you.